# SQL 2017 Standard Availability Group

Tags: sql-server-2017, windows-server

I am working on creating an AG on SQL Server 2017 Standard and Windows Server 2016.  I have created the failover cluster using a file share witness and everything checks out OK with the cluster.  The only issue or warnings I get are related to only using 1 NIC for each server (These are VM's with multiple NIC's).  I can connect to the SQL instance using the windows failover cluster DNS entry.  When I down one server or manually fail over the cluster, the cluster DNS entry does not update to point to the new "failed over IP"  These 2 different IP's are on 2 separate subnets.  After some time (20 minutes) the DNS entry will update to the new (failed over) IP.  I have tried to adjust the TTL setting in the cluster name DNS entry however, it changes itself back to 20 minutes.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As you don't mention it, I suspect your application is not connecting with

```
MultiSubnetFailover=True
```

[SqlClient Support for High Availability, Disaster Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sqlclient-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery)

Comment: The application connecting is Java based and will not have a web.config that supports this option.  I believe my answer lies within a DNS setting but I am not sure what needs to be changed.

Comment: @BrianSmith if your application can't use MultiSubnetFailover=True , You can have DNS update more often, which will still leave you with down time between updates, but it is probably simpler to just to put the servers on the same subnet. If you look around a bit you will find some people suggesting 5 minute DNS updates.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating 2 listeners on both subnets.  Once I did this it created 2 DNS entries with the same hostname but 2 different IP's (2 subnets)  This seemed to solve the issue.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you be more clear on how this works?

Comment: My availability group within SQL spans 2 subnets.  I had to add a listener that fell within each subnet (2 listeners).